# A calculation of Riemannian soliton

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

From the gradient Riemannian soliton, following two equations can be deduced, see Blaga, A. M. (2020). [On almost Riemann solitons. arXiv preprint arXiv:2008.06413](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.06413.pdf).
$$\nabla^2 f+\frac{1}{n-1}Ric=\frac{(n-1)\lambda-\Delta f}{n-2}g$$
$$R=(n-1)(n\lambda-2\Delta f),$$
where $R$ is the scalar curvature of the Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. Now using these two equations, we have calculated the following

[image]

Which shows that $Ric=0$ whenever $\nabla_jf\neq 0$. But then all the Riemannian soliton becomes trivial. I am not able to find where I am doing wrong in the calculation. Please help.

Comment: Besides a transcription error in the first equation, isn't that conclusion exactly what the author states as Theorem 2.7?

Comment: Actually I am not considering Theorem 2.7, I want to draw some different result but in doing that I have stuck in the calculation. Can you please tell me what is exactly the correct equation?

Comment: In the first equation that you copied from the paper, the denominator for Ric should be n-2, not n-1. // Regardless, your conclusion is exactly the same conclusion that the author of the paper reached when $\lambda$ is constant; so it doesn't appear you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly wrote it n-1. Now I understand the conclusion. Thank you.